# Meaning of "Updated As Reported"

Tags: meaning, ambiguity, past-participles

I am not too sure about some particular sentence:

> [link](https://www.anthem.com/ca/health-insurance/provider-directory/doctor-details/family-practice-ok-norman-73071-cynthia-taylor-F2589C7CCE3A3FFCD0BDEE8370DDA326-3926642AA6C915356DCCDD5982A170B3-161-p)
>   (move mouse over the blue question mark)
>   Choose the ID that matches the office you want to visit. This information is reported by the doctor directly and ***updated as reported*** for each plan.

What could be the meaning of "*updated as reported*"?

Comment: This might help: The information is reported by the doctor, and it is updated as it is reported (for each plan).

Comment: This is actually ambiguous.  It *could* mean that they can only report what the doctor reports to them; essentially putting the blame for any wrong information back on the doctor-  they report it *as* (in the same manner or with the same accuracy) it's reported to them.  Or it could mean that the website information immediately reflects updates made by the doctor- they update it as (concurrently with) the doctor updates it to them.

Comment: Why would you see report as creation? Reporting something is sending a message, which can contain new information (create), information to be modified (update) and maybe even information to be deleted! The doctor _reports_ something to the system, and the system _updates_ the plan according to that report.

Comment: @DamkerngT. For the example, "*report*" is creation; "*update*" is modification. Modification cannot come before creation. So, in your answer "*it is updated as it is reported*", with both "*it*"s referring to the same piece of information, you seem to suggest that the information is updated (modified) before the said information is even reported (created).

Comment: @Jim Would  "*This information...is updated as* ***new information is*** *reported...*" be better?

Comment: @DamkerngT.   Would  "*This information...is updated as* ***new information is*** *reported...*" be better?

Comment: @meatie- It all depends on what was originally meant.  It certainly narrows it to one interpretation; but is it the right one?

Comment: @meatie The way I read it (to make it a reasonable sentence) is perhaps the simplest one: *this information* refers to the information that you would see (if the doctor reported it). It doesn't matter how many times the doctor reported or updated or will report or will update it. (Hence, the simple present.)

Comment: @DamkerngT.  So, the original is poorly written?

Comment: @meatie Because I can understand it just fine, I'm going to say that it was poorly written myself. (Though, of course, virtually everything in this world could be made better. Then again, they say, "The better is the enemy of the good.") Also note that the simple present has many uses; it doesn't have to be about "now". I believe that we can take this one as either simple-present-for-facts or simple-present-for-repeated-events.

Comment: @meatie I just noticed that I dropped *not* again (it's something happens to me quite often on ELL, perhaps because it's usually three or four words because I can see what I just typed). Anyway, what I wanted to say was "I'm not going to say that it was poorly written myself".

Comment: @DamkerngT.   But the original sentence is ambiguous nonetheless?

Answer (score 2):

> This information is reported by the doctor directly and ***updated as reported*** for each plan.

The second reported here is a participle with passive sense, exactly as in the head clause. Jim points out that *as* may be taken ambiguously:

> It *could* mean that they can only report what the doctor reports to them; essentially putting the blame for any wrong information back on the doctor- they report it as (in the same manner or with the same accuracy) it's reported to them. Or it could mean that the website information immediately reflects updates made by the doctor- they update it as (concurrently with) the doctor updates it to them.

That is, *as* may be either a comparative (= reported with the same meaning as the doctor's report) or a temporal locative (= reported at the same time as the doctor's report).

I suggest that it is more likely that the comparative sense is meant, and that the temporal implication is 'perfect':

> This information is reported by the doctor directly and [then] updated [with the same meaning] as [the doctor ***has***] ***reported*** [it] for each plan.

Comment: I'm wondering why this kind of ellipsis is legit in this case. I never came across it before. @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB It's not really ellipsis: the sense is inherent in the words and forms. Similarly, if I say "I pass on this news as reported", meaning I just tell you what I heard on TV, without adding anything, you understand "as" to mean "in the form in which it was", and you infer "on TV" and "without adding anything" from the discourse context.

Comment: In "**As** expected, he said little.", is this "as" adv or conj? @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB CGEL treats most of what traditional grammar calls 'subordinating conjunctions' as 'prepositions'; I'm OK with that.

Comment: Fine. One last Q: in your "I pass on this news **as reported**" and "This provision shall survive the termination of the discussions by either Party **as provided herein**.", are these two "as clause" adverbial clauses or attributive clauses? @StoneyB

Comment: @KinzleB Oh dear. After an exhausting discussion with another questioner here, I raised the question on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/182062/24489). I was not entirely happy with any of the answers there (most people missed the point); so for the time being the best answer I can give you is "Yes; they are adverbial clauses or attributive clauses."

Comment: I never expected you have the same confusion as mine. ^_^ Actually, this is what I wanted to post as a question. "As clauses" can be seen in all the contracts I read. @StoneyB